# Android App Links Assistant, avoid restarting the app

Tags: android, android-studio, applinks, android-app-links, android-studio-bumblebee

I am trying the App Links Assistant to test the browsable intents in my app as described in official doc (https://developer.android.com/studio/write/app-link-indexing) :

[image: app links assistant]

The problem, is that **whenever I test the App link, the app is always relaunched**:
[image]

This is a problem because I want to test the app when it is already opened but in backgrounnd (after user presses home button or launches a browser than then returns to the app)

**Is there a way to avoid this? or should I instead use the terminal to launch the intent?**

adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -c android.intent.category.BROWSABLE -d ‘schema:host' -a android.intent.action.VIEW